# EmguCV SetCaptureProperty default values

Tags: emgucv

I am using EmguCV in my C# project.
I have recently set the values of my usb webcam properties to some random doubles and integers to see how it works, but now my webcam seemed to remember all my unfortunate changes and the video is terrible even in a clean project.

The code I have used looked like this:

```
 capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Contrast, x);
 capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Brightness, x);
 capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.AutoExposure, x);
 capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Gamma, x);
 capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Staturation, x);
 capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Sharpness, x);
```

How do I know the default values of properties listed in EmguCV CapProp Enum?
Is there a way to reset to default webcam settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Settings, 1);